# Git through https

Tags: security, https, password, git, webdav

When I clone a repo with
    git clone https://username@domain.com/directory
or when I push to it with
    git push origin master

Git asks me for a password, how I can automatically provide the password, like ssh keys for example ? So that it don't asks me for my password anymore ?

I need this for two reasons:

1)automation, hudson for example

2)I'm too lazy to provide it everytime by myself

Second question (it's related with the first one)

Why they asks sometimes twice for the password ?

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing like the SSH agent for http, so you have to provide the password in cleartext. You can save the credentials to `~/.netrc`:

```
touch ~/.netrc
chmod 600 ~/.netrc
cat > ~/.netrc <<EOF
machine domain.com
login USERNAME
password SUPERSECRET
EOF
```

Note that the password is saved in clear text there. It is less secure than using encrypted SSH keys and ssh agent, but get's the job done. You are basically on the same security level as a default Subversion on most systems.

Note that newer versions of Git (> 1.7.0) make a better job of caching entered credentials, so you should only need to enter your password once there if you do not use the `.netrc`.

Comment: Doesn't work for me, git version is 1.7.0.4, still asks for my password

Comment: You obviously need to adapt the created .netrc to your needs. See http://linux.die.net/man/5/netrc

Comment: Sure :) is updated